# Jquery Append Parameter inside <a href='@Url.ActionLink()'></a>

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, model-view-controller, razor

I have the below code inside a Jquery function

```
$.each(array, function (index, value) {
                var id1 = value.match(/\d+/);
                $("#linksList").append("<li>" + value + "<a href='@Url.ActionLink("Details", "Jira", new { id ="${id1}" })'>" + value + "</a>" + "</li>");
            });
```

But I am not able to pass the parameter Id . I am getting random values assigned for Id as below . What am I doing wrong .

```
<a href="/Jira/Details/%2Bid1%2B"> jira_subtask_link 41102</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it worked for me

```
 $("#linksList").append("<li>" + "" + "<a href='/JIra/Details/" + id + "'>" + value + "</a>" + "</li>");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to mix because Razor exists server side while jquery is client side

Templating engines inject your C# code into the HTML/CSS/Js prior to its run. As such ASP .NET cannot render such a variable intelligible when it is ready to compile to client side source code, as that var's life cycle is client side/while the app is running. Its a compile time vs run time discrepancy

I think you may be better off

1. Saving that javascript variable to something you can send back to the controller
2. At the controller level, putting it into a model that can be passed to the view
3. Rendering the action link with that id as a variable coming from the view's model, and not from jQuery

I know it sounds a bit weird, but this is how server and client side code interact in templating engines

Additionally, a hacky approach may be to insert a "dummy" id string, and then using jQuery to replace that dummy text with your intended, actual id value

Comment: Thanks for helping ,but this Id is not server bind . We have it available. I just have to pass it .

Comment: Sorry can you clarify what you mean? What I am saying is that there is no passing values "across" or laterally from javascript straight into razor code because there *is* no razor code when the page is live...its already been compiled and injected into the html/css/js. Conversely, javascript code is only workable when the page is live. You can see the misalignment. As far as I know, Its either it gets passed back to controller from the view, gets put into a view model, and "re-templated" into the view, or you hack it with javascript to replace the dummy string when the page is live.

Comment: so instead of ActionLink whether I will be able to do it  with pure html tag

Answer (score 0):

razor code is compiled at server side and transformed in html, the client cannot understand razor syntax so if you want to have the same result from the client you have to use javascipt